# How to use a CSV field to define the node label in a LOAD statement

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

This example is taken from https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-importing-data-and-etl/#_importing_the_data_using_cypher"

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:customers.csv" AS row
    CREATE (:Customer {companyName: row.CompanyName, customerID: row.CustomerID, fax: row.Fax, phone: row.Phone});
```

What I want to do is use a field in the CSV file to define the label in the node. For example:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "FILE:///Neo4j_AttributeProvenance.csv" AS CSVLine CREATE (q:CSVLine.NodeType { NodeID:CSVLine.NodeID, SchemaName:CSVLine.SchemaName, TableName:CSVLine.TableName, DataType:CSVLine.DataType, PreviousNodeID:CSVLine.PreviousNodeID });
```

[image: Here is the error I get:]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Neo4j Cypher - creating nodes and setting labels with LOAD CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24992977/neo4j-cypher-creating-nodes-and-setting-labels-with-load-csv)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have a look at the [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_creating_data) procedures. In this case there's a procedure able to create nodes dinamically based on column values in your .csv file. The syntax is:

```
CALL apoc.create.node(['Label'], {key:value,…​})
```

In your case the simplest syntax should be:

```
CALL apoc.create.node(["' + CSVLine.NodeType + '"], {NodeID: "' + NodeID:CSVLine.NodeID + '", etc}) yield node
```

Comment: The jar file goes in the plugins folder of the current DB, but otherwise it seems to work. Awesome.

Comment: Yes sure, to install the apoc you need to put the .jar files into the plugins folder in your neo4j installation path.